# How to cast objects to generic dictionary?

Tags: generics, dictionary

The generic dictionary is as follows:

```
public class ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

And specific dictionaries can be as follows:

```
var container = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Unit>();
var container = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CustomUnitClass>();
```

These special dictionaries (with different parameters) have been added in Application state:

```
HttpContext.Current.Application[key] = container;
```

When I get the items from Application state (some people here helped me about that; Thanks them), I'm able to check if type is of ConcurrentDictionary in this way:

```
object d = HttpContext.Current.Application[i];
if (d.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ConcurrentDictionary<,>))
```

And the last point was left - how to cast object d to generic ConcurrentDictionary:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<?, ?> unit = d as ConcurrentDictionary<?, ?>;
```

I don't want to use specific cast as follows:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, Unit> unit = d as ConcurrentDictionary<string, Unit>;
```

because the second parameter can be of another type.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you might be looking at generics in a slightly wrong way, but that's okay, lets talk!

Your `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is perfect, and you're using it correctly, however I think when it comes to casting back, unless you explicitly know what the type is you're expecting, there's no *real* point in casting it.

Alternatively what I would recommend, for the purpose of strongly-typed loveliness; you mentioned that potentially the second type, aka the `TValue` will vary... this is a perfect time to use an interface! Let me demonstrate.

### Our interface

```
public interface IModeOfTransport
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Colour { get; set; }
    bool CanFloat { get; set; }
    bool CanFly { get; set; }
    int NumberOfPassengers { get; set; }
}
```

### Our objects

```
public class Car : IModeOfTransport
{
    // ...
}
public class Plane : IModeOfTransport
{
    // ...
}
public class Boat : IModeOfTransport
{
    // ...
}
```

### Our implementation

```
var modesOfTransport = new Dictionary<string, IModeOfTransport>();
modesOfTransport.Add("First", new Car());
modesOfTransport.Add("First", new Plane());
modesOfTransport.Add("First", new Boat());
```

### Let's take a break

As you can from the above, we have a dictionary with a key type of `string` and a value type of `IModeOfTransport`. This allows us explicit strongly-typed access to all of the properties and methods of the `IModeOfTransport` interface. This is recommended if you need to access specific information on a generic value within a dictionary, and you don't know what the actual object type cast is. By using interfaces it allows us to find similarities.

### Almost done

```
object dictionary = HttpContext.Current.Application[i];
if (dictionary.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
{
    var modesOfTransport = dictionary as Dictionary<string, IModeOfTransport>;
    foreach (var keyValuePair in modesOfTransport)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's almost what I want. But the problem is that there's nothing common for Car, Plane and Boat. How to design the IModeOfTransport interface in that case? If I try to create empty IModeOfTransport interface just as a marker nothing will be there at time when I want to get some data.

Comment: oh deer, that's okay let's think about this. What information are you trying to get out of your objects in the dictionary? Are you trying to get simple information like a `Name`, or is it something more complex?

Comment: The information we need are exactly what you said, simple strings, like names... But, they have slightly different property names as Name, UnitName, etc. By the way, that's not my design. I've just started working in one company and should do something based on current state.

Comment: The number of types that can be second parameter in the dictionary is not too big and I could check for every type, which is not so smart solution, but if nothing I can't do, I can do that - brute force method.

Comment: I empathise with your position. What I would recommend is; although the objects don't directly share similarities in the property names, is create an interface and "force" them too. I'm not suggesting re-jigging the logic, but instead if the interface has a property called `Name`, but the object property is called `LongWindedName`, have the object implement `Name` that returns `LongWindedName`.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I should change these particular classes such as Car, Plane, Boat. But, I can't do that. Is there any other way I could solve this issue?

Comment: Hmm, so we're unable to change the objects even slightly, and there is the potential that the object types will vary. Also, and this is where the problem is, the similarities with the objects differ ever so slightly... I fear the last resort may be a nasty switch statement. :(

Comment: Yes, it looks like the things are going to switch statement. Thank you very much for your help.