# How to access object's properties of Application_Error event in Global.ASAX?

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting

I am currently writing a generic error handler with logging for an application, which should extract useful information from the sender object.

Let me first give you some background before I ask my question:

The **Application_Error** handler in **Global.asax** which I am using for that purpose is defined as follows:

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

When I set a breakpoint inside of this method, I am getting through the locals window a lot of useful information from the sender:
[image: Sender_Object_Global.asax]

In the type column, Visual Studio suggests the object is of type `ASP.global_asax`, but this seems to be an artificial type because when I am trying to cast it like

```
var senderInfo = (ASP.global_asax)sender;
```

I am getting the following error:

> CS0246: The type or namespace 'ASP' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

---

### Questions:

1. **Event parameter:** Is there a way to cast **`sender`** into a suitable class type containing all the info the Locals window is showing? (**Note** that I don't require the static and non-public members the debugger is showing)
2. **Exception object:** Likewise, can this be achieved for the exception object as well? (You can see in the screen shot that `exc` is of type System.Exception, but the exact type is `System.Web.HttpUnhandledException`. This could be especially useful for `exc.InnerException` because here we're getting the real info about the reason why this exception occurred.)

   ```
       var exc = Server.GetLastError();
       var innerExc = exc.InnerException;
   ```

---

**N.B.** I found some similar questions in Stackoverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827565/how-to-cast-objects-to-generic-dictionary) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835215/how-can-i-cast-object-dynamically)) but they are not duplicates because they are dealing with different topics.

Comment: **I like to learn from your feedback!** Downvoting tells me there is something wrong with this question, but I have no clue what. Help me to improve this question! Comment or edit it (or upvote it if you find it helpful).

Comment: IMO, there is nothing wrong with this question. @denchu has already pointed you in right direction.

Comment: @Bozhidar: Thank you for your confirmation. I was just wondering because I got 1 upvote and 1 downvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `System.Web.HttpApplication` for this.

[image: Sample debug image]

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed helpful!